# Read local file

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to read XMl local file, but' ive got the error: **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'** I must add that stream is null.

Below is my code:

```
InitializeComponent();
var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("AppXMLTEST.MyResources.XMLFile.xml");
ObservableCollection<Person> PersonInformation;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));
PersonInformation = (ObservableCollection<Person>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
listView.ItemsSource = PersonInformation;
```

Comment: if stream is null, then it stands to reason that the name you are using for your resource is incorrect.  Have you checked that?

Comment: Right-click on the file in Solution Explorer and choose Properties. In the Properties window, under the Advanced section, use the drop-down list next to Build Action to set a build action for the file. And make sure the option is **Embedded Resource**

Comment: Thank you @Lucas Zhang - MSFT. This is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: I will post it as answer could you accept it, which will help more people

Comment: Yeah sure no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the file in Solution Explorer and choose Properties. In the Properties window, under the Advanced section, use the drop-down list next to Build Action to set a build action for the file. And make sure the option is **Embedded Resource** .

[image]